# why my angular code is not working?

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this simple code in angular as a learning exercise, but I don't understand why I get the wrong result in my browser.

The result i see in the browser is the text *"{{helloMessage}}"* and not *"Hello World"*.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the output, and I don't see any error in the browser:

[image]

Comment: may be angular.js not import correctly!!!

Comment: angular.js is import correctly for sure.

Comment: you created a function `HelloWorldCtrl` not an `ng-controller` .

Comment: @ gaurav bhavsar => can you please explain what i did wrong

Comment: this might help: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/guide/controller

Comment: what is display iin console?

Comment: @Yanshof check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9aWQu3HBBN59g2IuIK9?p=preview)

Comment: your code is fine. see my answe.

Comment: check the update in my answer to change your src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your code work correctly!!!!!!

```js
  function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
   <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: upvoted you for your fine finding. But injecting the src at the top is a must

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

// call your myApp
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

```
// create your angular app
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

// create ng-controller inside your angular myApp
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
}
```

Check this working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9aWQu3HBBN59g2IuIK9?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working for a few reasons.

1. You aren't creating an instance of an Angular application. Controllers must exist as a property on an existing angular app.
   It can be created like this. `angular.module('app',[])`
   and now the controller could be appended to it like so:

   ```
   angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('HelloWorldCtrl',HelloWorldCtrl);

   function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
      $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
   }
   ```
2. You are not using the Angular dependency injection properly. You can make sure the your `$scope` parameter is injected at runtime by using the `$inject` property like this:

   ```
    angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('HelloWorldCtrl',HelloWorldCtrl);

    HelloWorldCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
       $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
   ```

With those changes, the code works. See [working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZYWYp?editors=1111)

Comment: Not true, brother see my answer and working plunker. he just injected the angularjs after the controller. I deserve your upvote :P

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked You're right - and you got my upvote. I still don't like it though, it's a little too janky for someone who is new to Angular and should be learning best practices and the proper way to set things up.

Comment: yup, but his question focuses on one thing and you just killed the fly with a CANON :). You deserve upvote for your through explanation though :) but his code isn't working not for the reason you have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all fine. Just inject the src i.e `<script src="angular.js"></script>` before the ng-controller. Make sure your `angular.js` file is in the root.
 Your code's **plunker**:http://plnkr.co/edit/Nhmg9FYJlHy9IwVsIJ0x?p=preview

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I suppose your src to angular.js isn't at the root. Try removing `<script src="angular.js"></script>` and **adding**
 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>` in its place.

Comment: where is your brother?? i mean the sources you have provided must not be full then. Do you have something like brother.html?

Comment: did you check my plunker? i don't see brother anywhere in you explanation in the question.

Comment: @Alex Rumba Nicked if inject src after ng-controller its work agian.

Comment: @hadiJZ then his problem must be the source to his angularjs

Comment: @Yanshof can you change your source <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> for <script src="angular.js">

Answer (score 0):

when you want to render a angularJs application variable In HTML, It must be defined inside angular context. since this function is not defined in angular context but only as a javascript function, it's not working.

function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){ $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World"; }